# How to make 15 textured billiard balls roll?

Tags: python, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a rigid body physic simulation of 15 billiard balls breaking from the hit of a white ball, and they all work well hitting and bouncing from each other, except they don´t rotate like real ones will do rolling over the pool table.

How to make them roll without having to animate them one by one?

I´m using Blender 2.78c latest version in with windows 10 Intel(R)Core(TM)i7-4900MQ CPU@2.80GHz, RAM 16.0 GB and 64-bit operating sys, x64 based processor. I´m new to blender and wonder if there could be a python script to do the rolling, and/or if I have to use the game engine instead of the cycles one I´m using right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have [collision bounds](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/properties.html#rigid-body-collisions) set to [sphere?](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Blender-Physics#/Image:Use-Blender-Physics-Step-7.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You need just basic rigid body options, imho, there's the standard collision and rotation damp. Just set the collision shape to mesh, always behave better for collisions. Also you can lower collision margins (not zero, at least .01).

it should work like this:

[image]

here is the test .blend:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming you don't know about rigid body and the physics tab. If it is a ball you want, go to the physics tab by clicking on the object and then going to the tab with a bouncing ball with a blue trail as the icon. In that, it should have 9 options. Click rigid body, and then go down to the bit that says "Rigid body collisions". Set it to a sphere. If the ball falls through the floor, then go onto the floor and go to the physics tab and click rigid body, but this time don't set it to sphere and at the top where it says active, change it to passive so that the floor doesn't fall too.

Comment: You don't need the game engine for that, as the person above me suggested. And you most certainly don't need python for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I thought a python script was the answer, but is not. Is just the rigid body settings. Thanks. Simpler than I thought. Yes, completely new to it.